# Dispatch Flash Event when person closes browser

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have an RTMP stream loading and would like to know the drop off time of the video. Is there a method of knowing when a person abruptly leaves the video session by closing the window, back button, address bar, etc?

Or do i need to make an external interface call from JavaScript to Flash using something like onunload & onbeforeunload events?

I am guessing that it is the later, but wanted to see if there was a method of keeping all my code inside of AS3.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered listening to the following event: `flash.events.NetStatusEvent` from your `NetConnection` object?

**I read on [Adobe's forum](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/590915) that the `NetStatusEvent` event could be part of the solution although it seems its not enough in all cases.** Some mention a ping functionality or databases log to find out when exactly the client disconnected.

**I would try to combine the `NetStatusEvent` functionality with a Javascript listener.**

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of is to use JavaScript, but you can avoid relying on an external script by embedding the JavaScript inside your AS3, then use document.write through ExternalInterface, eg:

```
var script:XML = <javascript>
    <![CDATA[
        window.onbeforeunload = function() { 
            [do flash callback here] 
        }
    ]]>
</javascript>;
ExternalInterface.call("document.write", '<script type="text/javascript">' + javascript.toString() + '</script>');
```